# Meaning of “un interdit”

Tags: sens, expressions

What is the meaning of the French word “interdit” in the context of the expression “comme un interdit”, which is the title of a song by French singer Christophe?

Answer (score 7):

"Interdit" is mostly used as an adjective; but as a noun it means "taboo" and so, a possible translation is "**taboo**"; however, other options such as "**line not to cross**" can be meaningful. In the particular context of this song, nevertheless, "**forbidden fruit**" would be a better translation.